# Incorrect checksum error when processing OLAP project

Tags: sql-server, ssas, checksum, olap

We have a couple of jobs set up during the night which are processing our OLAP projects. A couple of times in the past few weeks the following error has occurred:

> Processing [project name]:Error: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0x6d4444f7; actual: 0xf331a6f0). It occured during a read of page (9:3591725) in database ID 2 at offset 0x000006d9c5a000 in file 'D:\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\temp8.ndf' [...] HY000.

...with, of course, different values for checksums, pages and temp files.
The problem happens completely at random and we can't really figure out the cause. Our servers are on a data centre so we can't really do much in the way of hardware checks. DBCC CHECKDB of the tempdb database when run in the morning returns - of course - nothing.
I haven't stumbled across any of the articles online about this problem with regards to OLAP processing. Could you at least point me in some direction so I could find out how does OLAP processing use tempdb databases and files, what could a potential cause for this be and what steps to take to prevent it from occuring again?

Comment: I'd want to check the server logs to make sure the server was available at the time your process was running and not down/rebooting or running a back up / restore with logins disabled?

Comment: The only thing I could find in the event log around that time is the following error:

"The shadow copies of volume D: were deleted because the shadow copy storage could not grow in time.  Consider reducing the IO load on the system or choose a shadow copy storage volume that is not being shadow copied."
Source: Volsnap, Event ID: 25.
However, this error came up at 04:39:41.

The OLAP processing error is also visible in the Application event log, but already at 04:04:58.
What's interesting, though, is that only more than 2 hours later was the processing of the package reported as failed

Comment: The error is coming from the Sql Server. The "logical consistency" error could indicate an issue with the underlying disk / storage medium.  Also, since the issue is from the TempDB files, you can try to re-create your TempDB with a new set of files in a new drive / location.